# Extracting maven dependencies on artifact build

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, ide

I need to extract the contents of two jar files into the root directory of my jar file upon the artifact being built. This used to work when I had static dependencies in a libraries folders and simply added them under my Output Structure tab as "Library Files", but now it only includes the jar files rather than the contents of them in the root directory of the artifact.

[image: The Output Structure pane]

It confuses me as to why this happens and I've played around with a few parts, but can't find a solution. All I need is the extracted files to be within the output jar file, rather than the libraries just being places in the jar (if I haven't said that a few times already).

All current code, like the pom.xml, can be found on [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/jammehcow/Lukkit/).

What the jar should look like:

```
|- lua.class
|- luac.class
|- luajc.class
|- luajc$1.class
|- luajc$InputFile.class
|- luajc$LocalClassLoader
|- META-INF
|- org/luaj
|- config.yml
|- plugin.yml
|- unwrittenfun - Main package
```

What it ends up looking like:

```
|- luaj-jme-3.0.1.jar
|- luaj-jse-3.0.1.jar
|- config.yml
|- plugin.yml
|- unwrittenfun - Main package
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Why do you need to extract the content of the jar files to build your other jar file? Why not using them as usual dependencies which is done by maven? Furthermore better use text instead of links to images cause many people can not access those binary content...

Comment: @khmarbaise mate, I'm new to maven and how to build things with Java, I just infer from the docs. As for the reason I need them extracted, that's just how I've always used them when it's in production. All releases of the plugin prior have been in the same format. I'm not quite sure what you mean, it's just how it's been done and I'm sticking to it. Makes it easy for me to understand.